# How to prove $M\in O^+(n,1)$ can always be decomposed to the product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, hyperbolic-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

To be specific, I want to prove that for any $M\in \mathbb{R}_{(n+1)\times (n+1)} $ (**See update below**)
$$
M^T
\begin{bmatrix}
I_n & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
I_n & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
there exists $Q$ and $B$ that
$$
Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\quad \text{where }Q_0\in O(n)\\
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{n-1} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cosh t & \sinh t \\
0 & \sinh t & \cosh t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfying $M=QB$.

I don't have any idea. I can only think of writing $M$ in the form of a block matrix.
$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
M_0 & \alpha\\
\beta ^T & x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
substitute it into the first equation will come to
$$
M_0^T\alpha=x\beta\\
\alpha^T\alpha-x^2=-1\\
M_0^TM_0-\beta \beta^T=I_n
$$
I don't know how to introduce $Q_0$, not to say B.

Any help please?

---

**Update**: Sorry for misstating. $M$ should be $M\in O^+(n,1)$, the subgroup of isometries that are time orientation-preserving (physicists
call it the orthochronous Lorentz group), and $B$ should be any matrix of a Lorentz boost.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.
You may use `\cosh t` for $\cosh t$ so that the function $\cosh$ is rendered without italics.

Comment: In the first equation, $M$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, but $\begin{bmatrix}
I_n & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$ has one more row and column than $M$, so the matrix product can't be defined.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Thanks for pointing out! Type fixed.

Comment: This is obviously false if you look at the sign pattern of the bottom row of your $QB$. However, in general, $M$ can be expressed in the form of $(Q_1\oplus\pm1)B(Q_2\oplus1)$.

Comment: @user1551 I don't quite understand why this is obviously false. If $Q_0=I_2$ then $QB$ should meet the requirement. As for the general form you mentioned, could you kindly provide the proof process if possible?

Comment: For instance, $M=-I$ is a solution to the given equation, but the bottom right entry of your $QB$ is $\cosh t$, which is always positive. Thus $QB$ cannot possibly be equal to $-I$. In other words, your choices of $Q$ and $B$ don't exhaust all possibilities of $M$.

Comment: You are misstating the Cartan  decomposition, it is KAK, not KA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false. The bottom row of your $QB$ has the sign pattern $(0,\ldots,0,\ast,+)$, but this is not necessarily the case for $M$ when $M=-I$ or $$
M=\pmatrix{\cosh t&&\sinh t\\ &I_{n-1}\\ \sinh t&&\cosh t},\ n\ge1,\,t\ne0.
$$

It is true, however, that $M=(Q_1\oplus\pm1)B(Q_2\oplus1)$ for some $Q_1,Q_2\in O(n)$ and some $B$ that takes the form as specified in your question.

Let $M=UP$ be the polar decomposition of $M$, where $U$ is orthogonal and $P$ is positive definite. Let $D=I_n\oplus-1$. From $M^TDM=D$ we infer that
\begin{align}
PU^TDUP&=D,\\
DUP&=UP^{-1}D,\\
(DUP)^TDUP&=(UP^{-1}D)^TUP^{-1}D,\\
P^2&=DP^{-2}D=(DP^{-1}D)^2,\\
P&=DP^{-1}D,\\
\end{align}
where the last line is due to the fact that every positive definite matrix has a unique positive definite square root. Now partition $P$ as $\pmatrix{A&b\\ b^T&c}$ where $A\succ0$ and $c>0$. Then
$$
I=DPDP=\pmatrix{A&b\\ -b^T&-c}\pmatrix{A&b\\ -b^T&-c}=\pmatrix{A^2-bb^T&(A-cI)b\\ b^T(A-cI)&c^2-b^Tb}.
$$
Therefore $c\ge1,\ b=(c^2-1)^{1/2}u$ for some unit eigenvector $u$ of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $c$, and $A^2=I+(c^2-1)uu^T$. Hence $A=I+(c-1)uu^T$ and
$$
P=\pmatrix{I+(c-1)uu^T&(c^2-1)^{1/2}u\\ (c^2-1)^{1/2}u^T&c}
=\pmatrix{Q_2^T\\ &1}\underbrace{\pmatrix{I_{n-1}\\ &\cosh t&\sinh t\\ &\sinh t&\cosh t}}_B\pmatrix{Q_2\\ &1}
$$
where $c=\cosh t$ and $Q_2\in O(n)$ is any orthogonal matrix whose last row is $u^T$.

It follows that $M=QB(Q_2\oplus1)$, where $Q=U(Q_2^T\oplus1)$. So, from $M^TDM=D$, we obtain $Q^TDQ=B^{-1}(Q_2\oplus1)D(Q_2^T\oplus1)B^{-1}=B^{-1}DB^{-1}=D$. Hence $DQ=QD$ and $Q=Q_1\oplus\pm1$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q_1$. Now we are done.

**Edit.** If you also require $M$ to be a member of the orthochronous group (i.e. $M^TDM=D,\,\det(M)=1$ and $M_{n+1,n+1}\ge1$), then the $Q$ above must take the form of $Q_1\oplus1$ (rather than $Q_1\oplus\pm1$) with $\det(Q_1)=\det(Q_2)$. The matrices $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ can be chosen from $SO(n)$ if $t$ is allowed to be negative.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, my bad. You're right. I did miss some requirements when describing the statement. The original statement is that $M \in O^+(n,1)$, that is, orthochronous Lorentz group. It should not be reduced to $M^TDM=D$, though this is indeed one of the conditions it should meet. If you know something about this and have an idea of how to prove this under such conditions, please let me know if it's convenient for you. Overall, thanks for your nice answer and sorry for the wrong statement!