# Isometry groups of $\mathbb H^n(R)$ (hyperbolic spaces)

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, isometry, mobius-transformation

I know that the group of isometries on $\mathbb H^n(R)$ is $O^+(n,1)$ (the orthochronous lorentz group) which i have proved using the Hyperboloid model.

I have also been able to show for n=2 case considering half plane model the isometies are composition of Mobius transformation and reflection (with respect to the imaginary axis).
Also I have shown that the isometry group is isomorphic to $PSL(2,\mathbb R)\rtimes_\alpha\frac{\mathbb Z}{2\mathbb Z}$, where $$\alpha :\frac{\mathbb Z}{2\mathbb Z} \to \text{Aut}(PSL(2,\mathbb R))$$ $$\alpha(1)=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
-c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I am unable to link this two informations for n=2. Is there a way to see a similar thing in higher dimensions? if possible suggest some reference regarding representations of  $O^+(n,1)$, as I don't understand much about them.

Comment: In any dimension, there is an isometry from the hyperboloid model to the half-space model. Therefore, you can take the formula for any isometry of the hyperboloid model and calculate the formula for the corresponding isometry of the half-plane model.

Comment: And sir @Deane what about the representation of $O^+(n,1)$?

Comment: What do you mean by the representation of $O^+(n,1)$? Do you mean the theory of representations in general? You've already found the standard representation, which is the set of isometries of the hyperboloid model.

Comment: Okay sir . I found something here ...https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3923518/779382. This helped

Comment: An isometry of Euclidean space is the composition of a translation (which moves the origin) and a rotation (which fixes the origin). There is a similar decomposition here. Look up “boost” in the context of Lorentzian transformations to see what  “translations” of hyperbolic space are.

Comment: Thank you sir. It helped